# Is there a way to get user pfp using discord api directly

Tags: javascript, discord

So for my react project I will like to get my discord bot's pfp and show it on my site.
So what would be the appropriate URL for it? like what would even be the method since as far as I know you will need to have the scope perms for that. So what should I do to make this work? Looked up discord docs but it was too vague for me